# how to using NEST .net client binaryfile indexing

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch

...

Hello guys

how to binary files indexing in elasticsearch is it possible? this is my code but error 400 maybe I think 'PUT /index/_doc/'no id'" how can I send to add Id???

```
  private static async Task FileIndexingAsync()
    {
        var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);
        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
        var fileName = "328c1ca988554b21874fe43fa16335d0.bin";
        string path = "C:\\documents\\ETC\\connectorData\\"+ fileName;

        Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        String base64FileContent = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        Debug.WriteLine("base64FileContent : " + base64FileContent);
        string pk = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
        var binary = new[]
        {
            new binary
            {
               Id = pk,
               name = fileName,
               blob =base64FileContent
            }
        };
        var response = await client.IndexAsync(binary, idx => idx.Index("test_binary"));
        Debug.WriteLine("FileIndexingAsync : "+ response);
    }
```

Comment: I have to ask: why you want to do this? It doesn't seem like a good idea to store arbitrary binary files in ES.

Comment: My boss wants whether elasticsearch can replace PostgreSQL so I trying this code and I said that is elasticsearch can't however he want to know why not